# Send push notifications with PHP

Tags: push-notification

I am thinking of trying to implement push notifications into my website. Essentially I would just need to message individual users of personal updates not everyone that has agreed. I have looked and researched a lot and its confusing where to start, what I need, what language to use etc.

I use 1and1.co.uk for my hosting and would like to use PHP to instigate the push. Is this possible from what they offer and if so where do I start?

All the paid stuff seems to offer just bulk notifications and that is not what I need and why should I pay for it if its possible to do myself.

Also how difficult and time consuming is the process?

If I get enough advice and manage to get it working, I will write a step by step tuition as there is nothing out there with a simple answer and instructions.

Thanks and regards

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "push notifications"?  Are you trying to push data from the server to users actively on the site?  Send emails or other notifications to all users at regular times?  Something else?

Comment: Basically if a user gets a message from another user I want the user go get a notification on their browser like facebook does

Comment: Then what you're looking for is called Web Sockets.  It allows the server to maintain a connection with JavaScript code on the client and send data over that connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it in time, you can do it using Ajax polling, which means executing Ajax requests every few seconds.

Comment: isnt polling a toll on the server?